# Completion of hyperbolic 3-manifold (Thurston's lecture note)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

I need help with a part of Thurston's lecture note.

p.55~56 in [the 4th lecture note](http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/4.pdf) states that when obtaining hyperbolic manifold by gluing polyhedra having some ideal vertices, the set of derivatives of the holonomy $\left\{| H'(\alpha)|\right\}$ determines the completion of a deleted neighborhood $N(v)$ of an ideal vertex $v$.

I really get in trouble seeing why this should be.

Is there any meterials in which I can find some hints? Any little one would be appreciated.

Comment: added some more tags, hope you get an answer

Comment: Did you check the book by Benedetti and Petronio on hyperbolic manifolds?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that book, and now I found what I want. Thanks studiosus.